# simulating linux command with pipes don't work

Tags: c, linux, shell, pipe

I'm new to Linux and using pipes with C.
I'm trying to write a program executing the command: `ps aux | grep root | wc -l` using pipes.

The problem is that my program doesn't show anything in the terminal, not like the original command!

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // exit
#include <stdio.h>  // printf
#include <unistd.h> // execlp

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int p1[2], p2[2];
int f1, f2;

if(pipe(p1) == -1) {
    exit(1);
}

if(pipe(p2) == -1) {
    exit(2);
}

f1 = fork();
if(f1 < 0) {
    exit(1);
} else if(f1 == 0) {

    close(p1[1]);
    close(0);
    dup2(p1[0], 0);
    close(p1[0]);

    close(p2[0]);
    close(1);
    dup2(p2[1], 1);
    close(p2[1]);

    execlp("grep", "grep", "root", NULL);

} else {

    f2 = fork();
    if(f2 < 0) {
        exit(2);
    } else if(f2 == 0) {

        close(p2[1]);
        close(0);
        dup2(p2[0], 0);
        close(p2[0]);

        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);

    } else {

        close(p1[0]);
        close(1);
        dup2(p1[1], 1);
        close(p1[1]);

        execlp("ps", "ps", "aux", NULL);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Removed greetings per [convention](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <unistd.h> 
 #include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

    int p1[2], p2[2];
    int f1, f2, f3;
    if(pipe(p1) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }   
    f1 = fork();
    if(f1 < 0) {
        exit(1);
    } 
    else if(f1 == 0) {
        dup2(p1[1], 1);
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p1[1]);
        execlp("ps", "ps", "aux", NULL);
        perror("ps");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pipe(p2) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }
    f2 = fork();
    if(f2 < 0) {
        exit(1);
    } 
    else if(f2 == 0) {
        dup2(p1[0], 0);
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p1[1]);
        dup2(p2[1], 1);
        close(p2[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "root", NULL);
        perror("grep");
        exit(1);
    }
    f3 = fork();
    if(f3 < 0) {
        exit(1);
    } 
    else if(f3 == 0) {
        dup2(p2[0], 0);
        close(p2[0]);
        close(p2[1]);
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p1[1]);
        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", NULL);
        perror("wc");
        exit(1);
    }
    close(p1[0]);
    close(p1[1]);
    close(p2[0]);
    close(p2[1]);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother :)

Comment: Some comment to support this answer and explain what it solved, is always better than bald code.

Comment: He created 3 threads each thread executed a command, while I created 2 threads and the 3rd command is executed by the main thread ! notice that execlp() replaces the code of the thread with the code of the command ! maybe that's the problem of my code, peace :)